# query last LTS version with Launchpad API

Tags: lts, launchpadlib, launchpad-api

Is there any option to query the Launchpad API for a list of all LTS releases?

Otherwise, I can get the releases and their status by

```
from launchpadlib.launchpad import Launchpad, STAGING_SERVICE_ROOT

cachedir = "/tmp/launchpadlib/cache/"
lp = Launchpad.login_anonymously('ppastats', 'edge', cachedir, version='devel')
launchpad = lp
[s.status for s in launchpad.distributions["ubuntu"].series]
```

But how to filter this by the LTS criterion?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid Launchpad doesn't really know about this itself in a straightforward machine-readable way, so it can't export that information right now.  Your best bet is probably going to be something like filtering on the description, although I believe that most scripts that need to know this right now simply hardcode the list since it changes infrequently.

Also, please don't use "edge", as it's long-obsolete and exists only for compatibility.  Use "production" instead.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason you can't just assume that the oldest active release is the oldest LTS? LTS are the longest supported so there'll never be a non-LTS outliving an LTS. Eg:

```
>>> [s.name for s in lp.distributions['ubuntu'].series if s.active][-1]
'precise'
```

Also, LTS's are released in April of even-numbered years, so to get ALL currently supported LTS you could do a trick like this:

```
>>> [s.name for s in lp.distributions['ubuntu'].series if s.active and s.version.endswith('.04') and not int(s.version.split('.')[0]) % 2]
['trusty', 'precise']
```